# libfreenect error: "Error looking up function 'freenect_set_depth_format': libfreenect.so"

Tags: java, jna, kinect

I get the following error when making the [Java JNA Wrapper](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Java_JNA_Wrapper#Compilation) for [libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.openkinect.freenect.FreenectTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.138 sec <<< FAILURE!
org.openkinect.freenect.FreenectTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'freenect_set_depth_format':
/home/richard/libfreenect/wrappers/java/../../build/lib/libfreenect.so: 
undefined symbol: freenect_set_depth_format
```

I am using Xubuntu 11.10 for which the [Ubuntu Manual Install](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Ubuntu_Manual_Install) works fine using freeglut3-dev instead of libglut3-dev. I am able to run glview successfully.

Has anyone else experienced this error?

Has anyone been able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the web and in the last post on the page the user mentions that he was able to find a solution. I hope it helps.

From https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/239  :

around line 190 change

`freenect_set_depth_format(this, fmt.intValue());`
to
`freenect_set_depth_mode(this, fmt.intValue());`

and

`freenect_set_video_format(this, fmt.intValue());`
to
`freenect_set_video_mode(this, fmt.intValue());`

and at the end change

`private static native int freenect_set_depth_format(NativeDevice dev, int i);`
to
`private static native int freenect_set_depth_mode(NativeDevice dev, int i);`

and

`private static native int freenect_set_video_format(NativeDevice dev, int i);`
to
`private static native int freenect_set_video_mode(NativeDevice dev, int i);`